# How do you parse a concatenated string of integers to find powers of 2?

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

Project: 2048 Microservice with flask and python, where the grid is a concatenation of digits into a string (this is mandatory).

exG = ‘02000201600040000’

How can I parse this string for powers of 2? My idea is to use a switch case on the leading number:

```
if leading number starts with 2:
    check for 2048
    check for 256
    if not, it is 2 and can be assigned
if leading number starts with 1:
    check for 1024
    if not, it is 128....
```

What I would like to get is
newList = {‘0’, ‘2’, ‘0’, ‘0’, ‘0’, ‘2’, '0', ‘16’, ‘0’, ‘0’, ‘0’, ‘4’, ‘0’, ‘0’, ‘0’, ‘0’}

However, my brain is missing something when working with two digit+ numbers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the expected output.

Comment: That output doesn't make sense, why isn't there a `'0'` between `'2'` and `'16'`?

Comment: do you need 0's as well?

Comment: Are there any limits on how large your powers of 2 can be, or is every possible slice a potential candidate to be a valid entry?

Comment: Also how would something like '64' be handled, would that give a list ['64'] or do you need ['64', '4']?

Comment: Also, 1 is a power of 2 as well! 2^0 = 1. However, 0 is NOT a power of 2

Comment: @Neeraj yes I would as they signify the empty squares.

Comment: @HenryEcker it would only be ['64'] and the largest is ['2048']

Comment: How would you know that you want the number 2048 instead of the separate numbers 2, 0, 4, 8 because they are all powers of 2

Comment: @SoySoy4444 I edited my post to clarify, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumptions in the question that:

- 0 is a power of 2 (it is not)
- 1 is NOT a power of 2 (it is)
- We do not want duplicates, so for a number like "64", we only want "64" and not "4".

```
import math
exG = "02000201600040000"
check = "" #current string of values you need to check.
newList = []

for str_digit in exG:
    check += str_digit

    if check == "0": # 2 is NOT a power of 2, but OP wants it to be included
        newList.append(check)
        check = ""
    elif check == "1": # 2 IS a power of 2, but OP wants it to be excluded
        continue
    elif math.log(int(check), 2).is_integer(): #math.log() returns a float, so if the float is an integer, then the number is a power of 2
        newList.append(check)
        check = ""
    # else, number is NOT a power of 2 and is not 0. 
    # Then, we want to test the current number concatenated with the next number, so we don't reset check

print(newList)
```

Comment: Fails if given a power of 2 which has a power of 2 as a prefix. (Eg. the eponymous 2048)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but here's my attempt:

```
import re
import itertools
import math

a="01000201600040000"
_2048=re.split("(2048)",a)
_1024=[re.split("(1024)",x) for x in _2048]
normalized_1024=list(itertools.chain(*_1024))
final_split=[list(filter(None,re.split("(0)",x))) if (len(x)!=4 or x.startswith("0")) else x for x in normalized_1024 ]

op=[]
for i in final_split:
    if isinstance(i,list):
        for _i in i:
            if (_i != "1") and (int(_i) & (int(_i) - 1)) == 0:
                op.append(_i)
    elif isinstance(i,str):
        #print(i)
        if (i != "1") and (int(i) & (int(i) - 1)) == 0:
            op.append(i)
        
print(op)
```

we first look for 2048 then split, similarly for 1024 and finally 0s. and finally we check if the number is a power of 2. the check includes 0 but excludes 1.
Also, while splitting, we keep the separator.